# How to have dynamic height in a div?

Tags: jquery, css

I am wondering if I can add a style to a div which calcualtes some % of height minus X pixels.

Any ideas apart from jQuery?

Comment: There is the experimental [CSS calc() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

Comment: @A.Wolff It is implented in all modern browsers. So no need to worry about it.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal What about Opera?  EDIT: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc  looks like only Opera mini could be an issue, which then isn't really one...

Comment: This is amazing from vendor that Opera has been updated but not Opera-mini.

Comment: @A.Wolff What opera says is: `As of version 8, the default mode of Opera Mini on iOS uses the iOS Safari engine, though Mini mode can be enabled.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS3 calc  e.g.  height: calc(100% - 20px);

Comment: Thanks! Thats actually works pretty well. is there scss implementation?